# The weighted distribution function for combination of two variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

For example, we have two random variables $a$ and $b$. And they have cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ and $H(x)$. We have number $0 < p < 1$.

Suppose, some machine get this random variables. 
So, what algorithm should it use to these variables to get new variable $c$ with cumulative distribution function $G(x) = p*F(x) + (1 - p)*H(x)$?

Sadly, I have no idea. :(

Comment: Generate independent samples of random variables $X$ and $Y$. Run a third random number generator that creates a discrete random variable $W$ that takes on values $1$ and $0$ with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$. Then, choose $X$ if $W = 1$ and $Y$ if $W=0$ to create a sample of $Z$ whose cumulative distribution function is $G(x) = pF(x)+(1-p)H(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Try
$$
Z=UX+(1-U)Y
$$
where $X\sim F$, $Y\sim H$ and $U\sim \mathrm{bin}(1,p)$ is a binomial distributed random variable such that $X,Y$ and $U$ are independent

Comment: Acapello: And compare with @Dilip's comment, which presents a bit differently the same construction.